# Variable declaration anywhere in the file

Tags: c

I was referring to the book "Theory and Problems of Programming with C" by Gottfried (Schaum's Outline series) In page number 224 section 8.5 in chapter 8 (Book whatever I have is Second edition). According to the book, 
"In order to access an external variable in another file, the variable must first be declared within that file. ***This declaration may appear anywhere within the file***. Usually, however, it will be placed at the beginning of the file"

I felt that it is not possible to keep the declaration of the variable anywhere in the file even in case it is a global variable. It should be placed before variable's usage. I tried and get error message if I place the declaration at th end. I am not sue if author's intention here is something else? Any comment on this? Attached is the image of the section from the text book.
[image]

Comment: This is not about global variables, but about `extern`. Does that change anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the variable can appear at file scope but also at block scope.

```
void foo(void)
{
    extern int x;
    x = 42;
}
```

The author didn't mean that the variable can be declared after it is used.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the author meant you can declare a variable anywhere as long as it is before using it, it may be anywhere in the file and not only at the beginning of it.